# unable to fetch id value of a row from a gridview to delete the particular row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I am trying to delete a particular row from a gridview based on the value of a particular `column(column Id)` for that row.

the gridview looks like:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grd_issuesDetails" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grd_issuesDetails_RowDataBound"
                                 GridLines="None" Width="600px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnPageIndexChanging="grd_issuesDetails_PageIndexChanging"  DataKeyNames="id"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="grd_issuesDetails_SelectedIndexChanged"     onrowdeleting="grd_issuesDetails_RowDeleting">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="img_name" HeaderText="Image name" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>

                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="teacher_code" HeaderText="Teacher code" ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="issue_date" HeaderText="Reported date" ></asp:BoundField>     
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resolve">
                                     <ItemTemplate>  
                                     <asp:Button ID="Buttonid"   runat="server" CommandName="fetch" Text="Fetch" OnClick="Button_fetch"></asp:Button>                                  

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                           <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />

                                           <asp:TemplateField>

    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:ImageButton ID="img_user" runat="server" CommandName="Select"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Status") %>' Width="20px" Height="20px" />

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">

                    <ItemTemplate>



                       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png"/>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>

                       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-update.png"/>

                       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-Cancel.png"/>

                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>

                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="ADD" Text="Add" ></asp:LinkButton>

                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>                    
                                </Columns>
                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0000CD" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="white" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                                 <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Right" CssClass = "GridPager" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

the codebehind:

```
 protected void grd_issuesDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        string id = grd_issuesDetails.DataKeys[grd_issuesDetails.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();

        //int row = Convert.ToInt32(grd_issuesDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from [Issuereport] where id= '"+id+"' ", con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


    }
```

I get the error :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
>   of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index

Source Error:

```
Line 123:        {
Line 124:
Line 125:            string id = grd_issuesDetails.DataKeys[grd_issuesDetails.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
Line 126:
Line 127:            //int row = Convert.ToInt32(grd_issuesDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```

Comment: Please read up on parameterised queries to make your SQL safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by using:

```
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(grd_issuesDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from [Issuereport] where id= '"+id +"' ", con);
```

Comment: Give yourself the check mark when the problem was answered by someone is not nice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string id = grd_issuesDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[your cell vaule index like 1,2... whatever].Text.Trim();
```

just pass id to your query